# Submit page using dynamic action javascript in Oracle apex

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to submit the page when I click a button, there are a couple validations I want to do first and I don't want to use the built in one for it so I'm creating one using javascript dynamic action. Most of it works just fine, just the submit page doesn't execute. Using this documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/apex.page.html

My code is essentially

```
if (...){
//some things i want to run first
apex.submit('submit');
alert("aaaa")
}else{
...
}

Everything but the submit as well as the code after submit works just fine. Not too sure what's wrong with it.
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Just created DA on a button with only ```apex.submit('submit');``` as code and page submits fine.

Comment: The other thing you could do is apply those "some things" in the client side condition of a Dynamic Action, where the true action includes a declarative Submit action, and the the false actions are your 'else'

Answer (score 0):

Are your page processes are executed when page is submitted with the request 'submit'?
Also you can try the console of your browser and just execute  apex.submit() without any request specified to see if the page is submitted or not.

Answer (score 0):

make any process to execute needed actions

in server side condition area //
type => request = value //
value => requestName //

then go to your JS code (dynamic action ) and then add this
apex.submit('requestName');